# Rights to tomcat6 ON Ubuntu server?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I have installed Ubuntu Server at home, with tomcat server checked at installation.  Everything work fine. But now, i have deployed inside tomcat my web application which is suppose to create some dicrectories to store files (photos, documents ...). I couldnt figure out in what directory i could create those ones and upload files there.

So basically, which directory is availaible to tomcat6 where i will be able to write and read ? Or , how could i give rights (read and rights) to tomcat6 ON some directories?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has it's own folder called webapps, where you normally deploy the application. Tomcat also has it's Manager GUI to deploy app. Some details can be found here.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html

With regard to "where i will be able to write and read" I won't put too much trust on bundled tomcat with Ubuntu, you better check the the permission and the ownership for the folders or files.

If you are on Linux,

```
ls, chmod, chown
```

are some of the command you can use.

Hope that helps.